# E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable'

Tags: java, android

I tried to run the application that I created in android studio,
Coding was no error, but the application forceclose.

Error log

> ```
> 01-14 03:49:32.389 8122-8122/com.kareem.kdevelop.listjualmobil E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
> 01-14 03:49:33.159 8122-8122/com.kareem.kdevelop.listjualmobil E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>      Process: com.kareem.kdevelop.listjualmobil, PID: 8122
>      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kareem.kdevelop.listjualmobil/com.kareem.kdevelop.listjualmobil.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2219)
>        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
>          at com.kareem.kdevelop.listjualmobil.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
>          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2163)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269) 
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045) 
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String[][] data = new String[][]{
        {"Honda, Brio, 1.2L CKD S A/T, 2015",
                "http://imgcdn.rajamobil.com:8080/resize2/public/media/images/databasemobil/mobilbaru/color/Brio%20-%20Brilliant%20Sporty%20Blue%20Metallic.png?v=420","19 Juta", "Jakarta Selatan"},
        {"Honda, Jazz, RS 1.5 A/T, 2015",
                "http://imgcdn.rajamobil.com:8080/resize2/public/media/images/databasemobil/original/2016/12/15/S1V6xervpWJK8rWnOqhxSve86RCb7VxK.JPG?v=493.83983572895","19 Juta", "Jakarta Selatan"},
        {"Mazda, Mazda2, V 1.5 M/T, 2014",
                "http://imgcdn.rajamobil.com:8080/resize2/public/media/images/databasemobil/mobilbaru/color/mazda2-abutua.jpg?v=420", "Tangerang"},
        {"Honda, Jazz, A 1.5 M/T, 2015",
                "http://imgcdn.rajamobil.com:8080/resize2/public/media/images/databasemobil/original/2016/12/19/otxIMI39Mq7o6QROZ7GJr_sm-TkizvNz.jpg?v=526.36904761905","Rp. 207.500.000", "Jakarta Barat"},
        {"Mitsubishi, Outlander, Sport PX, 2015",
                "http://imgcdn.rajamobil.com:8080/resize2/public/media/images/databasemobil/original/2016/11/17/81y5XBNeCNUQ-wUvaB6q7eSYc7D3XGr8.JPG?v=492.82786885246","Call", "Tangerang"}
};

private ListView lvItem;
private ArrayList listItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lvItem = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_item);
    listItem = new ArrayList<>();

    MobilModel mobil = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        mobil = new MobilModel();
        mobil.setTitle(data[i][0]);
        mobil.setImage(data[i][1]);
        mobil.setHarga(data[i][2]);
        mobil.setLokasi(data[i][3]);

        listItem.add(mobil);
    }

    MobilAdapter adapter = new MobilAdapter(MainActivity.this, listItem);
    lvItem.setAdapter(adapter);

    lvItem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            MobilModel mbl = (MobilModel) listItem.get(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailMobilActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(DetailMobilActivity.KEY_ITEM, mbl);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`data[2]` only has three elements, and will thus not have an index 3.

Answer (score -2):

The error in your question does not match the title of your question.

The error in your question is:

> ```
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
>          at com.kareem.kdevelop.listjualmobil.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
> ```

The problem is this line: `mobil.setLokasi(data[i][3]);`.  Your array has only three elements, with indexes 0, 1, and 2. You need to add a fourth element to your array to have an index 3.

Comment: The title in his question is caused by the error. i have too experienced the same.

Comment: Actually, it is not. Read the stack trace carefully and you'll see that the log message about RippleDrawable is just that: a log message. The error is `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity`, which is caused by the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`. RippleDrawable has nothing to do with it at all.