# Could not find class android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable

Tags: java, android

There is an error like this in my logcat. I checked out other post, but couldn't help.

```
Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```

Comment: First: Add code! Nothing can be solved without code. Further, google that error. I count 6 posts on the first page alone from Stack Overflow.. And add **the full error**! That means stacktrace, not just the one-line "what error is this" and add code relating to that stacktrace

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960223/could-not-find-class-android-graphics-drawable-rippledrawable-error) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474297/could-not-find-rippledrawable) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643601/e-dalvikvm-could-not-find-class-android-graphics-drawable-rippledrawable)

Comment: Your `compileSdkVersion` needs to be 21 or higher. More specifically, your `compileSdkVersion` needs to match the major version of the Android Support library that you are trying to use.

Comment: @CommonsWare Compile SDK Version is 25

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate - it is caused by a different method, in code that is already protected by a build version check.

Comment: It is however the same as this one, which to date also has no answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448661/could-not-find-class-android-graphics-drawable-rippledrawable-android-studio-2